# How to measure channel capacity performance for enhanced speech samples in GSM speech coders?

Tags: signal-processing, capacity, audio-codec, speech, channel-coding

I've been conducting some research lately on Speech Enhancement of the ITU-T Recommended G.729 Voice Activity Detection (VAD) algorithm for GSM Speech coders.

It has been suggested in the [literature](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323903291_Training_Supervised_Speech_Separation_System_to_Improve_STOI_and_PESQ_Directly#:%7E:text=Short-time%20objective%20intelligibility%20%28STOI%29%20and%20perceptual%20evaluation%20of,may%20be%20better%20choices%20for%20the%20loss%20function.) to measure the performance of speech enhancement algorithms using Perceptual Evaluation of Speech Quality (PESQ), and Short Time Objective Intelligibility (STOI).

So far I have been able to compute these measures including Signal-To-Noise Ratio (SNR).

But what bugs me is this post on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection#:%7E:text=In%20cellular%20radio%20systems%20(for%20instance%20GSM%20and%20CDMA%20systems)%20based%20on%20Discontinuous%20Transmission%20(DTX)%20mode%2C%20VAD%20is%20essential%20for%20enhancing%20system%20capacity%20by%20reducing%20co%2Dchannel%20interference%20and%20power%20consumption%20in%20portable%20digital%20devices.), that says:

> VAD is essential for enhancing system capacity by reducing **co-channel interference** and **power consumption** in portable digital devices.

So, I have been wondering how I would go about measuring the performance of the system/channel capacity in terms of ***co-channel interference and power consumption*** using an enhanced speech sample.

I have been researching this issue for the past 3days now, and all that I could find was this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221616673_Effect_of_GSM_speech_coding_on_the_performance_of_Speaker_Recognition_System), though it doesn't clearly address my issue.

Please does anyone have any idea/suggestion on what I could do to go about measuring the co-channel interference and power consumption level of an enhanced speech signal?